# prestashop: cannot insert image in tinymce

Tags: tinymce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

as admin, when trying to edit product description, using TinyMCE to insert an image -
when trying to save the new description I get server error.

I followed recommendation from - https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/317986-after-upgrade-to-16-i-cant-add-images-in-the-editor-i-get-a-litle-square-with-a-black-x-black/
and I removed \img\cms.htacces
and indeed the problem was solved and now I can save product description with image.

but according to - https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/316255-cms-images-cant-be-displayed-unless-htaccess-file-is-deleted/
I now have a security problem.

so what should be .htaccess content? or is there another solution for TinyMCE problem?

my \img\cms.htacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
deny from all
<Files ~ "(?i)^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$">
    order deny,allow
    allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: What's your image extension ? For the moment your htaccess only allows jpg gif and png images

Comment: I try to insert gif image.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this file?

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
Require all denied
<Files ~ "(?i)^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$">
    Require all granted
</Files>
```

Since Apache 2.4 [`mod_access_compat`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_access_compat.html) has been replaced by [`mod_authz_host`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html).

[Here is an upgrading documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html)

Comment: I use apache 2.2.31, and since I re-renamed my original htaccess file to be used, it does work as expected ?!